# In-place QR update: deleting a column

Tags: linear-algebra

**Background**

I'm trying to do an update to a "thin" QR decomposition ($A = QR$, where $Q$ is $\mathbf{R}^{m,n}$, the first few columns (up to the matrix rank) of an orthogonal matrix and $R$ is upper triangular and square and $\mathbf{R}^{n,n}$).  The matrix itself is a full column rank "tall" matrix ($m \ge n$), and I'm periodically adding and removing columns from $A$ as part of a larger pivoting optimization algorithm.

I'm doing the decomposition in-place inside $A$ using Householder transformations, with the Householder vectors stored in the lower triangular portion of the matrix and $R$ stored in the upper triangular portion of $A$.  I need to store the diagonals for $R$ in another extra array.  So I only need $\mathcal{O}(n)$ more memory beyond the space of the matrix being decomposed itself.

**Requirements**

At each step of the pivoting algorithm, I need to calculate

$$R^T(Rx - Q^T f)$$
$$Q Q^T f $$

The $Q^T f$ term in both equations can be calculated without needing to store $Q$ directly just by applying each Householder transformation to $f$ as they come in from newly added columns.  That is, at each step $f_{n} := H_n f_{n-1}$ for some Householder transformation $H_n$.  Unfortunately I don't see a way to update $Q Q^T f$ in the same way without explicitly storing $Q$ somewhere, so my guess is I still need to hold on to $Q$. ($Q Q^T f$ is basically the projection of $f$ on to the column space of $A$).

**Updating**

When deleting a column, all the literature I've found recommends using a series of Givens rotations for the "downstream" columns to push them from Hessenberg form back to triangular form.  However, I don't have anywhere to store these so I can calculate $Q Q^T f$ when I need it.  For the column being removed I need to keep it available to be re-added in the future, so I can't use it for scratch space.  Ideally I'd like to do the decomposition using only $\mathcal{O}(n)$ additional memory beyond the space provided by $A$ in the first place.

**My question**

Is there some other way to push the downstream columns back to triangular format that wouldn't use more memory?  I've tried to think of a way to update the Householder transformations, but I haven't been able to figure out a way that isn't $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.  I'd like the update itself to be $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ as it is with the Givens rotations.

Alternatively, is there a way of updating $Q Q^T f$ at each stage in the pivoting algorithm when a column is added or removed from $A$ without explicitly storing $Q$?

Comment: You certainly can't compute $QQ^Tf$ incrementally, but couldn't you just compute it completely at the end?  You never need to construct $Q$, just use the Householder reflectors as you are doing now.

Comment: Yes, if Q was _just_ made from Householder reflectors I could do that.  The problem is the Givens rotations to push the R matrix back to triangular form when a column is deleted: they're also part of the final Q matrix.  So if I wait to calculate $Q Q^T f$ until the very end, I need to hold on to the Givens matrices in some for or another.  It's just not clear where to store them in the mean time.  Worst case there could be $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ of them.

Comment: I don't understand where you get a Hessenberg matrix.  But this isn't really my field.

Comment: If you take a triangular matrix and remove a column in the middle of it, all the columns to the right of the removed one are basically in Hessenberg form.